# Change if an input text is disabled or enabled

Tags: jquery

In my program the user will be alowed to change his/her name, email and username by clicking the button "edit", i already have the attribute disable on each input text, but when i put the function on the button it doesn't change the status.

Here's the code of the input texts:

```
<input type="text" class="nameClient" disabled="true"/>
<input type="text" class="usernameClient" disabled="true"/>
<input type="text" class="emailClient" disabled="true"/>
<input type="button" class="editSubmit" value="Edit" />
```

And here's the code of the function:

```
$('.editSubmit').click(function() {
    $('.nameClient').removeAttr(disabled);
    $('.emailClient').removeAttr(disabled);
    $('.usernameClient').removeAttr(disabled);
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: use `.prop("disabled",false)`

Comment: glad it works :)

Answer (score 0):

`removeAttr` takes a string value: `removeAttr('disabled')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can used `.attr()` function

```js
$('.editSubmit').click(function () {
  $('.nameClient').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
  $('.emailClient').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
  $('.usernameClient').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h:inputText  class="nameClient" value="#{client.name}" disabled="true"/><br />
<h:inputText class="usernameClient" value="#{client.username}" disabled="true"/><br />
<h:inputText class="emailClient" value="#{client.email}" disabled="true"/><br />                               
<input type="button" class="editSubmit" value="Edit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use prop ( )

By using removeAttr(), you are completely removing the disabled attribute itself - while prop() is merely setting the property's underlying boolean value to false.

```
`$('.nameClient').prop("disabled",false);`
```

Warning given in removeAttr method page.

*Note: Removing an inline onclickevent handler using .removeAttr()doesn't achieve the desired effect in Internet Explorer 8, 9 and 11. To avoid potential problems, use .prop()instead:*